# client denied by server configuration: app/etc/local.xml

Tags: apache, magento, apache-config

I have installed magento on one of my [test server](http://202.137.248.5/InhousePortfolio/eCommerce/Jewelry/magento/1/jewelleryStore/) to study the features

Here when i navigate thru the admin site or upload some pictures for any product, the apache server will stop . When i opened the apache error log it is written as

```
[Wed May 18 16:34:34 2011] [error] [client 172.23.1.2] client denied by server configuration: D:/Projects/InhousePortfolio/eCommerce/Jewelry/magento/1/jewelleryStore/app/etc/local.xml
[Wed May 18 16:34:55 2011] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Wed May 18 16:39:28 2011] [warn] pid file C:/Program Files/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.11/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed May 18 16:39:28 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.2.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 18 16:39:28 2011] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Wed May 18 16:39:28 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5796
[Wed May 18 16:39:28 2011] [notice] Child 5796: Child process is running
[Wed May 18 16:39:28 2011] [notice] Child 5796: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed May 18 16:39:28 2011] [notice] Child 5796: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed May 18 16:39:28 2011] [notice] Child 5796: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Please let me know what is the problem.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Googling has a number of results that look good: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=client+denied+by+server+configuration

Answer (score 4):

Please check the Yireo site for answer:

http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/1322-client-denied-by-server-configuration-appetclocalxml

Comment: His solution deletes the error message but doesn't delete the error itself. CloudFlare still does a 522 for me but this time with no errors logged...